# Not able to scroll to the element in a dropdown using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, protractor

I am trying to select a checkbox from a dropdown in jq widgets. Now the code works when the element is in view but not otherwise. I understand that we need to scroll to element for protractor to be able to find it. I tried using executeScript and scrollIntoView here but am not able to scroll to the element. I tried a few other things as well. Please help me with this.

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['jq.spec.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeOutInterval: 30000000
    },
}
```

My jq.spec.js:

```
describe('should check jq widgets', function() {

    it("should check the scrolling is proper",function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdropdownlist/checkboxes.htm?arctic');
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('#dropdownlistContentjqxWidget')),500000,'dropdown did not display');
        $('#dropdownlistContentjqxWidget').click().then(function(){
            $('#listitem0innerListBoxjqxWidget>div').click();
            scrollIntoView(element(by.xpath("//span[text()='Francisco Chang']/parent::div/div")));
            element(by.xpath("//span[text()='Francisco Chang']/parent::div/div")).click();
            browser.sleep(10000);
        });
    });
});

var scrollIntoView = function(element){
    browser.executeScript(function(element) {
        element.scrollIntoView();
        }, element.getWebElement());
    });

};
```

//errors:

```
Failures:
1) should check jq widgets should chech the scrolling is proper
  Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //span[text()='Francisco Chang']/parent::div/div)
```

Comment: I still need help on this one. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your `scrollIntoView` function. The wrapper for jasmine resolves everything into the control flow but since it returns void, I am pretty sure this starts execution of `scrollIntoView` and returns immediately (before `browser.executeScript` gets added to the control flow. Then you try to click on the element without it being scrolled into view. Also for completeness I added a JSDoc:

```
/**
 * Scroll to find some element in the view
 * @param {ElementFinder} element the located element of interest
 * @returns {webdriver.promise.Promise} returns a webdriver promise
 */
var scrollIntoView = function(element){
    return browser.executeScript(function(element) {
        element.scrollIntoView();
        }, element.getWebElement());
    });
};
```

Comment: I tried this just now. Its still the same. Also, I cannot see the scrolling visually also.

Comment: Why are you turning off synchronization? Are you testing a non angular page?

Comment: Yes, its a non-angular page

Comment: Then you need to provide your own waiting logic between clicks and selecting. I also am think that expected conditions does not work when ignore synchronization is set to true.

Comment: I will replace expected conditions with sleep for now. I think I tested clicks and selecting using then as well. I will give this another go.

Comment: Yes, I checked my code..I did try this:         `scrollIntoView(element(by.xpath("//span[text()='Francisco Chang']/parent::div/div"))).then(function() {
                element(by.xpath("//span[text()='Francisco Chang']/parent::div/div")).click();
            });`